# Icarus verilog dump memory array ($dumpvars)

Tags: arrays, memory, verilog, dump, icarus

I try to dump an array (reg [31:0] data [31:0]) but I can't do it successfully.
I've tried the way that is in the iverilog wiki:

```
integer idx;
for (idx = 0; idx < 32; idx = idx + 1)
    $dumpvars(0,cpu_tb.cpu0.cpu_dp.cpu_regs.data[idx]);
```

It works, but 2 things happen.

1. A warning shows up: VCD warning: array word cpu_tb.cpu0.cpu_dp.cpu_regs.data[0] will conflict with an escaped identifier.
2. In GTKWave I have something like this in SST window: \data[0][31:0]

Is there any solution about that?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have e-mailed the mailing list of Icarus Verilog. Here are some answers:

> To dump an array word Icarus needs to escape the name so it is
>   compatible with the VCD dump format. That's what \data[0][31:0] is. It
>   is the zeroth  32-bit word of the data array. Because an escaped name
>   and an array name could now conflict Icarus produces the warning. It
>   would be best if it could check for an escaped identifier conflict and
>   only print a message when there is a problem, but as I remember this
>   was not possible.
>
> We chose to use escaped identifiers so that all the dumpers could
>   handle array words. The other common choice is to only support them
>   using a special dump command that only works with certain dump
>   formats.
>
> I agree it would be nice if we could make the warning more accurate,
>   but we are usually busy working on other things so minor annoyances
>   that appear to be complicated to fix do not often get fixed. As I
>   remember, and it has been a number of years, the issue is if you
>   search for the escaped identifier it find the array element and there
>   is no way in the VPI to search for the next occurrence. It's possible
>   that finding the array element in the Icarus search by name
>   implementation is a bug.
>
> Cary
>
> ---
>
> "To dump an array word Icarus needs to escape the name so it is
>   compatible with  the VCD dump format. That's what \data[0][31:0] is.
>   It is the zeroth? 32-bit  word of the data array. Because an escaped
>   name and an array name could now  conflict Icarus produces the
>   warning. It would be best if it could check for an  escaped identifier
>   conflict and only print a message when there is a problem,  but as I
>   remember this was not possible."
>
> ...I don't think that there's a need to escape the names.  Both VCS
>   (followed by fsdb2vcd) and CVC emit the name directly with no
>   problems.  Cut and paste example shown below:
>
> $var wire 5 `' IC_DrAd0 [3][4:0] $end $var wire 5 a' IC_DrAd0 [2][4:0]
>   $end $var wire 5 b' IC_DrAd0 [1][4:0] $end $var wire 5 c' IC_DrAd0
>   [0][4:0] $end
>
> I realize the VCD spec doesn't define this, but I've had to fold in a
>   lot of these kinds of extensions into gtkwave over the years as other
>   tools generate these constructs.  The escapes can cause save file
>   incompatibilities (missing signals) when trying to simulate on
>   iverilog versus VCS.
>
> Over time, SV constructs likely will cause further things added to the
>   VCD files.  AFAIK, the VCD part of the 1364 spec hasn't updated at all
>   since Verilog-XL.  CVC gets around possible incompatibilities by
>   adding a +dump_arrays plusarg (and no, you don't have to loop on each
>   array element either).
>
> -Tony

I also sent a mail to GTKWave creator Tony Bybell:

> Hello,
>
> The problem is that the compiler is not emitting those values into the
>   dump file.  You'll have to get in contact with the iverilog
>   developers.  I see the same problem if I run sim and compare against
>   another simulator such as CVC with +dump_arrays turned on which does
>   dump the arrays and they are visible in gtkwave.
>
> http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Release_Notes_Icarus_Verilog_0_9_2 |
>   Allow $dumpvars to accept array members for dumping,
>
> ...it looks like during "initial" time you might need to add a
>   $dumpvars statement for each array *element* you want dumped.  I don't
>   know if the array name by itself works.  Assigning each element to a
>   "wire" might work too.
>
> I have never tried this functionality in iverilog so I don't know if
>   it works. You might have to experiment or ask the developers.
>
> -Tony

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue recently:

When dumping vars with the for cycle like the question, this vcd error happens:

```
ERROR: $dumpvars cannot dump a vpiConstant.
```

My workaround is to generate n wires with assign statement assigning it the respective array word like this:

```
reg     [31:0]  registers [31:0];
generate
  genvar idx;
  for(idx = 0; idx < 32; idx = idx+1) begin: register
    wire [31:0] tmp;
    assign tmp = registers[idx];
  end
endgenerate
```

Now in GTKWave I have the generate blocks dumped correctly.

Comment: omg, it really worked. I just had to change the reg name to tmp instead reg.