# Is RawModule only for Top connections?

Tags: hdl, chisel

I'm writing a [SPI to Wishbone component with Chisel3](https://github.com/Martoni/spi2wb/blob/master/src/main/scala/spi2wb.scala), and for testing it on FPGA/real world I have to change the polarity of the reset (rstn).

To manage it I used `RawModule` for my Top module. And I used `withClockAndReset()` to change the reset polarity :

```
class TopSpi2Wb extends RawModule {
  val clock = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val rstn  = IO(Input(Bool()))
  // ...
   withClockAndReset(clock, !rstn) {
    val spi2Wb = Module(new Spi2Wb(dwidth, awidth))
    // module connections IO
  }
```

It seem's to works since I tryied to instanciate a Sync memory on the wishbone port. with this kind of code:

```
class TopSpi2Wb extends RawModule {
  val clock = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val rstn  = IO(Input(Bool()))
  // ...
   withClockAndReset(clock, !rstn) {
    val spi2Wb = Module(new Spi2Wb(dwidth, awidth))
    val wmem = SyncReadMem(1 << awidth, UInt(dwidth.W)) 
    val ackReg = RegInit(false.B)
    val datReg = RegInit(0.U(dwidth.W))

    ackReg := false.B
    datReg := 0.U(dwidth.W)
    when(spi2Wb.io.wbm.stb_o && spi2Wb.io.wbm.cyc_o) {
      when(spi2Wb.io.wbm.we_o){
        wmem.write(spi2Wb.io.wbm.adr_o, spi2Wb.io.wbm.dat_o)
        datReg := DontCare
      }.otherwise{
        datReg := wmem.read(spi2Wb.io.wbm.adr_o, spi2Wb.io.wbm.stb_o &
                            spi2Wb.io.wbm.cyc_o & !spi2Wb.io.wbm.we_o)
      }
  // ...
```

That *compile* without error, but I can't manage to read/write on memory correctly (with icarus). Verilog emitted seems to drop memory instantiation.

Maybe it's discouraged to write *chisel code* like Register, memories, ... and just instantiate **one** top module in RawModule no ?

Well, if I'm wrapping a *top* module in the RawModule, that works really better:

```
// Testing Spi2Wb with a memory connexion
// and reset inverted
class TopSpi2Wb extends RawModule {
  // Clock & Reset
  val clock = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val rstn  = IO(Input(Bool()))

  // Simple blink
  val blink = IO(Output(Bool()))

  // SPI
  val mosi = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val miso = IO(Output(Bool()))
  val sclk = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val csn  = IO(Input(Bool()))

  val dwidth = 8
  val awidth = 7

  withClockAndReset(clock, !rstn) {
    val spi2Wb = Module(new Spi2WbMem(dwidth, awidth))
    blink := spi2Wb.io.blink
    spi2Wb.io.mosi := mosi
    miso := spi2Wb.io.miso
    spi2Wb.io.sclk := sclk
    spi2Wb.io.csn := csn
  }
}
```

With the code above, all connection and register instantiation for Wishbone memory are done in `Spi2WbMem()` *standard* module.

Comment: It's very useful to have access to your repo but it's hard for me to repeat the error. Perhaps you could make a branch in your repo specifically demonstrating the error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting as much logic and state as you want in a RawModule. Just as a dumb sanity check, you have outputs that the memory is used to drive, correct? Otherwise it might be removed by DeadCodeElimination. If it's not something simple like that, a runnable example would be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jkoenig asked I re-written the module to reproduce the bug and ... [fixed it](https://github.com/Martoni/spi2wb/tree/bugrawmodule) !
Sorry for the inconvenience.

I had some difficulties to find the bug because Icarus [didn't dump the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317820/icarus-verilog-dump-memory-array-dumpvars#22395232) of memory and I thought it was not generated.

I think that my initial module wrapping fixed the bug without my realizing it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!